# HighCharts, multiple same chart on one page only uses 1 set of data

Tags: highcharts, windrose

If you can please look at: https://jsfiddle.net/eL0fnt1a/

I have 2 windrose charts on one page, each with a unique name and their own set of data.  However, the first set of data is used incorrectly for both charts.

I have others pages with multiple line charts and they work fine.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
    <div>
  <div id="ChartName0"></div>
  <div style="display:none">
    <table id="freq" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr nowrap>
        <th colspan="8" class="hdr"> Table of Frequencies(percent)</th>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <th class="freq"> Direction</th>
        <th class="freq"> 0-5 km/hr</th>
        <th class="freq"> 5-15 km/hr</th>
        <th class="freq"> 15-30 km/hr</th>
        <th class="freq"> 30-60 km/hr</th>
        <th class="freq"> 60-100 km/hr</th>
        <th class="freq"> > 100 km/hr</th>
        <th class="freq"> Total</th>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>North</td>
        <td class='data'>8.16326530612245</td>
        <td class='data'>12.244897959183675</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>NNE</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>NE</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>ENE</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>East</td>
        <td class='data'>20.408163265306122</td>
        <td class='data'>20.408163265306122</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>ESE</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>SE</td>
        <td class='data'>2.0408163265306123</td>
        <td class='data'>4.081632653061225</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>SSE</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>South</td>
        <td class='data'>2.0408163265306123</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>SSW</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>SW</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>4.081632653061225</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>WSW</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>West</td>
        <td class='data'>4.081632653061225</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>WNW</td>
        <td class='data'>4.081632653061225</td>
        <td class='data'>8.16326530612245</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>NW</td>
        <td class='data'>8.16326530612245</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>NNW</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>2.0408163265306123</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='totals'>Total</td>
        <td class='totals'>48.9795918367347</td>
        <td class='totals'>51.02040816326531</td>
        <td class='totals'>0</td>
        <td class='totals'>0</td>
        <td class='totals'>0</td>
        <td class='totals'>0</td>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>


<div>
  <div id="ChartName1"></div>
  <div style="display:none">
    <table id="freq" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr nowrap>
        <th colspan="8" class="hdr"> Table of Frequencies(percent)</th>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <th class="freq"> Direction</th>
        <th class="freq"> 0-5 km/hr</th>
        <th class="freq"> 5-15 km/hr</th>
        <th class="freq"> 15-30 km/hr</th>
        <th class="freq"> 30-60 km/hr</th>
        <th class="freq"> 60-100 km/hr</th>
        <th class="freq"> > 100 km/hr</th>
        <th class="freq"> Total</th>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>North</td>
        <td class='data'>9.036658141517476</td>
        <td class='data'>20.545609548167093</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>NNE</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>NE</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>ENE</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.08525149190110827</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>East</td>
        <td class='data'>5.797101449275362</td>
        <td class='data'>22.932651321398126</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>ESE</td>
        <td class='data'>0.3410059676044331</td>
        <td class='data'>0.42625745950554134</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>SE</td>
        <td class='data'>1.619778346121057</td>
        <td class='data'>1.8755328218243819</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>SSE</td>
        <td class='data'>0.08525149190110827</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>South</td>
        <td class='data'>1.1935208866155158</td>
        <td class='data'>0.2557544757033248</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>SSW</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>SW</td>
        <td class='data'>1.8755328218243819</td>
        <td class='data'>1.1082693947144076</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>WSW</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.17050298380221654</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>West</td>
        <td class='data'>2.7280477408354646</td>
        <td class='data'>0.5967604433077579</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>WNW</td>
        <td class='data'>3.7510656436487637</td>
        <td class='data'>11.082693947144076</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>NW</td>
        <td class='data'>5.797101449275362</td>
        <td class='data'>4.0068201193520885</td>
        <td class='data'>0.08525149190110827</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='dir'>NNW</td>
        <td class='data'>1.3640238704177323</td>
        <td class='data'>3.239556692242114</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0</td>
        <td class='data'>0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr nowrap>
        <td class='totals'>Total</td>
        <td class='totals'>33.589087809036656</td>
        <td class='totals'>66.32566069906224</td>
        <td class='totals'>0.08525149190110827</td>
        <td class='totals'>0</td>
        <td class='totals'>0</td>
        <td class='totals'>0</td>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    Highcharts.chart('ChartName0', {
          data: {
            table: 'freq',
            startRow: 1,
            endRow: 17,
            endColumn: 6
          },
          chart: {
            polar: true,
            type: 'column',
            backgroundColor: '#FEF5E7'
          },
          title: {
            floating: true,
            margin: 0,
            text: ' ',
            align: 'left'
          },
          credits: true,
          subtitle: {
            floating: true,
            margin: 0,
            text: ' ',
            align: 'left'
          },
          pane: {
            size: '80%'
          },
          legend: {
            enabled: true,
            align: 'left',
            floating: true,
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            y: 0,
            x: 0,
            layout: 'vertical'
          },
          xAxis: {
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            gridLineColor: '#8b4513',
            lineColor: '#321414',
            labels: {
              style: {
                color: 'black',
                fontSize: 14
              },
            },
          },
          yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            endOnTick: false,
            showLastLabel: true,
            gridLineColor: '#c19a6b',
            title: {
              text: 'Frequency (%)',
              style: {
                fontSize: '1.2em'
              }
            },
            labels: {
              style: {
                color: 'black',
                fontSize: 12
              },
              formatter: function() {
                return this.value + '%';
              }
            },
            tickAmount: 6,
            reversedStacks: false
          },
          tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '%'
          },
          plotOptions: {
            series: {
              stacking: 'normal',
              shadow: false,
              groupPadding: 0,
              pointPlacement: 'on'
            }
          }
        });
      Highcharts.chart('ChartName1', {
        data: {
          table: 'freq',
          startRow: 1,
          endRow: 17,
          endColumn: 6
        },
        chart: {
          polar: true,
          type: 'column',
          backgroundColor: '#FEF5E7'
        },
        title: {
          floating: true,
          margin: 0,
          text: ' ',
          align: 'left'
        },
        credits: true,
        subtitle: {
          floating: true,
          margin: 0,
          text: ' ',
          align: 'left'
        },
        pane: {
          size: '80%'
        },
        legend: {
          enabled: true,
          align: 'left',
          floating: true,
          verticalAlign: 'bottom',
          y: 0,
          x: 0,
          layout: 'vertical'
        },
        xAxis: {
          tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
          gridLineColor: '#8b4513',
          lineColor: '#321414',
          labels: {
            style: {
              color: 'black',
              fontSize: 14
            },
          },
        },
        yAxis: {
          min: 0,
          endOnTick: false,
          showLastLabel: true,
          gridLineColor: '#c19a6b',
          title: {
            text: 'Frequency (%)',
            style: {
              fontSize: '1.2em'
            }
          },
          labels: {
            style: {
              color: 'black',
              fontSize: 12
            },
            formatter: function() {
              return this.value + '%';
            }
          },
          tickAmount: 6,
          reversedStacks: false
        },
        tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: '%'
        },
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            shadow: false,
            groupPadding: 0,
            pointPlacement: 'on'
          }
        }
      });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: The problem is that you use the same `id` (`freq`) for the two tables. Ids in HTML are global and should be unique throughout the whole document. Change the second `id` to a different value and also its reference in the second chart's `data` section https://jsfiddle.net/z6ewm1uc/

Comment: Perfect, thankyou.  I can sleep again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@kikon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75303240/highcharts-multiple-same-chart-on-one-page-only-uses-1-set-of-data/75305064#comment132879464_75303240) solved the problem:

> The problem is that you use the same `id` (`freq`) for the two tables. Ids in HTML are global and should be unique throughout the whole document. Change the second `id` to a different value and also its reference in the second chart's `data` section jsfiddle.net/z6ewm1uc